# Does Laravel cache polymorphic calls?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

Got a polymorphic relationship like this: User -> polymorph -> subscription from various platforms. Toy but working example:

```
class Polymorph
{
    ...
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function subscription()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function isExpired()
    {
        return $this->subscription->isExpired(); // Checks an attribute
    }

    public function isActive()
    {
        return $this->subscription->isActive(); // Checks an attribute
    }
    ...
}

class User{
    ...
    public function poly()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Polymorph::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

And I'm doing:

```
$poly = $user->poly
$poly->isExpired(); // One DB call
$poly->isActive(); // No DB call
// etc..
```

It seems like Laravel caches the `$this->subscription` call. I'm looking at a query log as I'm calling these methods, and there is only one `SELECT` for the appropriate subscription object.

I looked through the docs, but don't think I found anything about it. Is it being cached? If so, what is it called or is there documentation describing it?

Comment: @Kaspars Bad example. Will replace it.

Comment: Laravel creates these properties with an Object of a certain class. Once created, it doesn't need to recreate and repopulate it. Acessing the property twice won't run the query again to fill it.

Comment: @Phiter Makes sense. It looks like I'll need to dig in and learn about the mechanism. Just wanted to make sure before I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **Yes**. Laravel caches the results of all relations once they are loaded so that the relation queries do not need to be run multiple time.

You can look [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2685-L2687) source.

```
public function getRelationValue($key)
{
    // If the key already exists in the relationships array, it just means the
    // relationship has already been loaded, so we'll just return it out of
    // here because there is no need to query within the relations twice.
    if ($this->relationLoaded($key)) {
        return $this->relations[$key];
    }
    // If the "attribute" exists as a method on the model, we will just assume
    // it is a relationship and will load and return results from the query
    // and hydrate the relationship's value on the "relationships" array.
    if (method_exists($this, $key)) {
        return $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
    }
}
```

I assume that you are talking about Laravel 5.2. As you can see, the relation results are cached in the `$this->relations` member of the model.